# Error appears when resuming the paused h264/mp4 streaming video from red5 server

Tags: flash, video-streaming, red5, mp4

I just met a piece of error log when I was trying to resume the paused mp4 streaming. Here is the log from the server:

> [INFO] [NioProcessor-1]
>   org.red5.io.mp4.impl.MP4Reader - Frame
>   position was not found for timestamp:
>   92000

I'm very new to Red5 so I don't know if this is a known issue, is it? And is there any solution so far?

I'm using Red5 newest 0.9.1 final for mac os x to stream the H.264/AAC encoded MP4 file to my flash app.

And there's no problem when I'm resuming the .flv file.

That's all the information I guess necessary. Any help is appreciated! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a lack of meta-data needed by players for proper seeking, etc. As of Red5 0.9.1 it will automatically generate the meta data for FLV files but doesn't for MP4 files.

I have no idea if this is something being added/fixed in the next release it's been quite a while since I've used Red5

You might be able to find another tool to add the meta data to the mp4

Comment: Just FYI, Adobe Media Converter is the only easy-to-use tool for adding meta data so far.